# Have makefile handle header file updates

Tags: c, makefile

When working in C/C++ programs, header files can become unmanageable when using multiple source & header files. I know that make lets you define file dependencies, such that a file is only recompiled if a dependency changes.

Let's say I have a (simplified) project that uses this structure:

- main.c depends on a.h
- a.h depends on b.h

I want to have a makefile that works somewhat like this:

```
run: exe
    ./exe

exe: a.h
    gcc main.c -o exe

a.h: b.h
```

The idea behind this would be that, by making a.h depend on b.h, if either a.h *or* b.h change, exe is re-compiled (this can also be done by having exe depend on a.h *and* b.h, but doing so would be unmanageable in projects with 20+ header files with their own dependency tree)

However, when I tried doing this (with some demo source & header files), changing b.h didn't result in exe recompiling.

main.c:

```c
#include "a.h"

int main() {
    printf ("magic number is: %d\n", MAGIC_NUM);
}
```

a.h:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"
```

b.h:

```c
int MAGIC_NUM = 42;
```

Even when I change the value of MAGIC_NUM, exe doesn't recompile. Is there some way of achieving this with make?

Comment: Far better and more reliable would be to generate the dependencies automatically. See https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

Comment: `but doing so would be unmanageable in projects with 20+ header files with their own dependency tree` - my experience is it is actually quite manageable. Stupid, yes, but manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use `gcc`'s `-MMD` flag to generate a makefile that contains header dependencies.

```
run: exe
    ./exe

exe:
    gcc main.c -o exe -MMD

-include exe.d
```

In use:

```bash
$ make
gcc main.c -o exe -MMD
./exe
magic number is: 42

$ cat exe.d
exe: main.c a.h b.h

$ sed -i 's/42/19/' b.h

$ make
gcc main.c -o exe -MMD
./exe
magic number is: 19
```